# Manually/programmatically selecting an item in jquery ui multiselect (version 0.3.1)?

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, multi-select

This version does not have the public refresh method, and I cant seem to find a way to do it.

I need to manually select items by value.

Here is a link to the version I am using, I am unable to change versions. http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

I am new to jquery and would appreciate any help. This widget is fantastic though :)

Many thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Documentation](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/):

> **How do I manually check or uncheck a checkbox?**
>
> The checkboxes can be accessed after calling the "widget" method.
>   Simply manually trigger the NATIVE click event on them:
>
> ```
> $("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox").each(function(){  
>     this.click(); 
> });
> ```
>
> The native click event must be used
>   (trigger('click') will not work) due to this bug in jQuery’s core.
>
> All necessary events and actions, like updating the button value, will
>   automatically fire.
>
> Alternatively, you could give the original option tag the selected
>   attribute, and then call MultiSelect’s refresh method.

To check the checkbox with a specific value, you could use something like this:

```
$("select").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='abc']").each(function() {
    this.click();
});
```